# Is it possible to call a key of a dictionary from within a nested dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, nested

I'm keeping some data stored within a dictionary. This dictionary contains a string as their keys, and nested dictionaries with a bunch of key:value pairs containing all the data associated to each key. Part of this data is the path to the files associated with the key, which all contain the key associated to them in their titles. So that it becomes easier to deal with all these file paths, is it possible to call the key of the nested dictionary from within the nested dictionary?

Here is an exemple:

```
exercises = {

    "1": {"audio": "./exercise_files/1_audio.mp3", "question": "./exercise_files/1_question.png", "answer": "./exercise_files/1_answer.png"},
    "2": {"audio": "./exercise_files/2_audio.mp3", "question": "./exercise_files/2_question.png", "answer": "./exercise_files/2_answer.png"},
    "3": {"audio": "./exercise_files/3_audio.mp3", "question": "./exercise_files/3_question.png", "answer": "./exercise_files/3_answer.png"},

}
```

As you can see, the "audio", "question" and "answer" keys are all asociated to a path, with the only difference being the number on the file title. I entered these file paths by hand, but it would would be complicated to do this with 50+ items. So it would be useful to be able to do it automatically, by only changing the number in the file title by the key of the entire dictionary itself.

I was expecting to be able to "navigate back" one step in the nested dictionaries hierarcy, and grab the key of the nested dictionary itself. (just like you can do with ../ when navigating through the path of a file, for exemple)

Here is an exemple of how it would work, if possible:

```
exercises = {

    "1": {"audio": f"./exercise_files/{#insert the "1" here}_audio.mp3", "question": "./exercise_files/{#insert the "1" here}_question.png"},

}
```

Thank you in advance!